# How can I run/call a python script while using swift?

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make an iOS app that will calculate pi to a set about of decimal places based on what the user wants. I currently have a python script that will take in an integer value from the user and then use that in the calculation of Pi. I also have a swift/Xcode project that will only allow a user to input an integer value. So I am wondering if there is a way for me to pass this value that the user enters from a textbox in my swift project to then give that to the python code, run it, and then output the result? In my python code, I am using "timer" to be able to calculate the time it takes to calculate pi to the set digits that was requested. So I would only need to be able to display this result.

I have thought about rewriting the python script into swift, but I am unsure of how to do that. This is the definition I am using in my python script to calculate pi:

```
def pi():
decimal.getcontext().prec += 2
three = decimal.Decimal(3)
first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, numb = 0, three, 1, 0, 0, 24, 3 
while numb != first:
    first = numb
    third, forth = third + forth, forth + 8
    fifth, sixth = fifth + sixth, sixth + 32
    second = (second * third) / fifth
    numb += second
decimal.getcontext().prec -= 2
return +numb
```

But I was unsure of how to rewrite this into swift language, so I figured getting swift to pass the precision value into python would be easier.

Comment: It's probably easier to rewrite the scrip in swift. Can you even execute python scripts in iOS?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I figured that if it was able to be executed by swift then it wouldn't make a difference if iOS can natively run them or not. I know that if I was to download an app I could run a python ide or python notebook on my device but I thought that if a python code was referenced by swift then it wouldn't cause much compatibility issues for this simple project.

Comment: Swift doesn't execute anything by itself, you will need to have Python installed. Why not learn a little swift and re-write your code, it's your only option I believe?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can run Python code in Swift since Python is designed to be embedded and has a C interface API. Check how [Swift for TensorFlow](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/site/tutorials/python_interoperability.ipynb) uses Python interoperability (although I couldn't find a quick way to only use that module and not the whole TensorFlow). You can also check [PythonKit](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit) out.

**However**, I don't think rewriting that script would be too difficult, and it might be better to avoid more libraries and dependencies in your project.

Edit: As Joakim Danielson pointed out, you'll need the Python runtime, and it doesn't seem to be available in iOS, so you seem to be limited to macOS for this.

Comment: You still need a python runtime, where do you have that on iOS?

Comment: My bad, didn't see the iOS tag.

Comment: @RenzoTissoni i was thinking about rewriting it in swift language, however I am currently unaware of swifts version of Decimal and being able to set the precision of said variable like you can in python. I know currently if I do it in Swift, I might be limited to only 15 place precision by default, that is unless I am unaware of a package/variable type that would allow me a varied precision based on users input.

Comment: Do you really need it? There are many way of calculating π to a certain number of digits, so why settling for the way you were using?